# 3d spiral with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I am very new to blender and the concept of noding but already excited about it.

I am trying to create a Fermat's spiral as part of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pigRs8uIiI (minute 1:30).

However, the object I get is 2-dimensional. I would like to extend it to 3d, more like a pipe. or a fossil :)
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
However, experimenting with the nodes did not help.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Hello. I don't get the issue. Is it just make Z vary?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I have updated the question

Comment: So this is about to calculate the radius so that the mesh goes side to side from a turn to the next one?

Answer (score 6):

That can be something like this:

[image]

The idea is to use Fermat's spiral calculation twice: at the angle and at the angle plus 2xPi.

That gives two points from which we can calculate the distance and in consequence the radius of the curve vertex.

[image]

As we calculate twice, the formula in inside a group (subprogram).

The radius is empirically scaled and clamped.

Additionally, the curve U resolution is set to 1 to avoid unnecessary geometry and artifacts.

In order to have the reversed part:

[image]

Take the previous result, reverse it and combine the flipped reserved and the initial result.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Archimedean spiral is available in `Distribute Matrices` node. So, we can make fermat's spiral by:

[image]

[image]